# Open h5 file to use with MNE python

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I am currently working on a project with The Virtual Brain ([www.thevirtualbrain.org](http://www.thevirtualbrain.org)) and simulated some EEG data. To analyse this further, I would like to open this simulated time series in python so I can analyse it using the MNE package. However, I can only store the EEG data from The Virtual Brain in h5 format and I can't figure out how to open this file in python in a way that I can use it to analyse it using MNE.

I can read in the h5 file in Python and see its description:

*file keys
<KeysViewHDF5 ['data', 'time']>
structure of data
<HDF5 dataset "data": shape (512, 2, 63, 1), type "<f8">
structure of time
<HDF5 dataset "time": shape (512,), type "<f8">*

But I don't know how to actually use this data to analyse it as EEG again.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Celien

Answer (score 0):

The 'keys' are the names of HDF5 nodes (either groups or data sets). To become proficient you need to understand HDF5 file schema. Spend some time reviewing HDF5 documentation at **The HDF Group**. I recommend this doc: [Introduction to HDF5](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Introduction+to+HDF5).

Based on your output above, you have 2 datasets:

1. HDF5 dataset "**data**": shape (512, 2, 63, 1), type "<f8">
2. HDF5 dataset "**time**": shape (512,), type "<f8">

h5py retrieves datasets as NumPy arrays. Shape is the shape attribute of the array, and type is the dtype attribute. (Familiarity with NumPy is also helpful.) In this case, all values are floats. Both datasets have 512 rows, but different dimensions.  I suspect the `time` dataset holds your time values. You will have to explore the `data` dataset to understand how that data is organized.

Here is pseudo-code to retrieve the data based on details in your question. `data_arr` and `time_arr` are NumPy arrays for the associated datasets.

```
with h5py.File('yourfile.h5','r') as h5f:
    data_arr = h5f['data'][:]
    time_arr = h5f['time'][:]
```

Once you have the data as NumPy arrays, you can work with it using Python and NumPy operations. This should get you started. Give it a try and see what you can do with `data_arr` and `time_arr`. Note: This is a quick overview HDF5 and h5py. There is a lot more to this subject.

Note I used Python's context manager `with/as:` instead of a simple `h5py.File()` call. It is preferred, and manages the file close operation for you (no need for `h5f.close()`)

Answer (score 0):

I asked myself the same question.

I think that this could be helpfull.

TimeSeries.h5 of TVB is hdf5 file with 2 datasets:

1. data (EEG traces)
2. time

We need *data* dataset (or both, if you need it).

```
import mne
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import welch
import h5py

with h5py.File('TVB_EEG.h5', 'r') as f:
    data = np.array(f['data'])
    
data = np.reshape(data, (data.shape[0], -1)).T
```

With these lines we'll transform TVB EEG data to array.

Now we might to create info and others requires to complete the conversion to mne dataset (channels, sampling frequency, etc):

```
ch_names = ['Ch' + str(i + 1) for i in range(data.shape[0])]
ch_types = ['eeg' for i in range(data.shape[0])]
sfreq = 1 / (data.shape[1] / 1000)
info = mne.create_info(ch_names=ch_names, ch_types=ch_types, sfreq=sfreq)

raw = mne.io.RawArray(data, info)

print(raw.info)
print('Duration:', raw.times[-1], 'seconds')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Creating RawArray with float64 data, n_channels=63, n_times=10000
    Range : 0 ... 9999 =      0.000 ... 99990.000 secs
Ready.
<Info | 7 non-empty values
 bads: []
 ch_names: Ch1, Ch2, Ch3, Ch4, Ch5, Ch6, Ch7, Ch8, Ch9, Ch10, Ch11, Ch12, ...
 chs: 63 EEG
 custom_ref_applied: False
 highpass: 0.0 Hz
 lowpass: 0.1 Hz
 meas_date: unspecified
 nchan: 63
 projs: []
 sfreq: 0.1 Hz
>
Duration: 99990.0 seconds
```

Now you be able to work with TVB EEG file on mne:

EXAMPLE:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[20, 5])
start_time = 0
end_time = 99990

ax.plot(raw.get_data(picks=2, tmin=start_time, tmax=end_time).T)
plt.show()



raw.plot_psd(fmin= 0, fmax=0.045)
plt.show()
```